# Unable to Decrypt Python Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I just started learning python and though the best way would be to solve few easy algorithm questions. I came across the question:

A strange grid has been recovered from an old book. It has 5 columns and infinite number of rows. The bottom row is considered as the first row. First few rows of the grid are like this:

```
    ..............

    ..............

    20 22 24 26 28

    11 13 15 17 19

    10 12 14 16 18

    1  3  5  7  9

    0  2  4  6  8
```

The grid grows upwards forever!
Rows are indexed from bottom to top and columns are indexed from left to right.
The task is to find the integer in **cth** column in **rth** row of the grid.

Example:
Input: 6 3

Output: 25

The number in the 6th row and 3rd column is 25.

The solution for this problem was:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
r = int(line.split(' ')[0])
c = int(line.split(' ')[1])

if r%2 == 1:
    print ((r-1)/2)*10 + (c-1)*2
else:
    print ((r-1)/2)*10 + (c-1)*2 + 1
```

I dint understand why are we taking `r%2 == 1` and why are we using `((c-1)*2)+1)+(((r-1)/2)`

Comment: I don't see `((c-1)*2)+1)+(((r-1)/2)` anywhere in the code. I do see `((r-1)/2)*10 + (c-1)*2` though. You probably just had a typo and forgot the `*10)` :P

Answer (score 2):

Look at just the odd-numbered rows. In column one the values are 0, 10, 20. In column two the values are 2, 12, 22. In column three, 4, 14, 24.

Now look at just the even-numbered rows. In column one the values are 1, 11, 21. Column two: 3, 13, 23. Column three: 5, 15, 25.

Do you see how as you move up the rows, the value increases by ten? Not on every row, but rather on every other row? This is why we have `((r-1)/2)*10` - first we round `r` down to the nearest multiple of 2, then we multiply by 10. This gives us the value in the tens place.

Look again at the odd-numbered rows. In row one, the values are 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. In row three: 10, 12, 14, 16, 18. Row five: 20, 22, 24, 26, 28.

Now back to the even-numbered rows. In row two we have 1, 3, 5, 7, 9. Row four: 11, 13, 15, 17, 19.

Do you see how in the rows, the values of the ones digits are increasing by two? In the case of the odd-numbered rows, they are the even numbers. In the even-numbered rows, they are the odds. This is why we have `if r%2 == 1`: to check if we are dealing with an odd or even row in order to handle this branching behavior.

If the `r` is odd, we calculate the `c-1`th multiple of 2 - this is `(c-1)*2`. On the other hand, if `r` is even, we calculate the `c-1`th multiple of 2, plus 1 (thus making the value odd). `(c-1)*2 + 1`.

Since the value generated by knowing the row number describes the tens digit, and the value generated by knowing the column number describes the ones digit, we can just add these two values together. That is `((r-1)/2)*10 + (c-1)*2` in the case where `r` is odd and `((r-1)/2)*10 + (c-1)*2 + 1` in the case where `r` is even.

Thanks John for the Edit suggestion!

Comment: You beat me to it! Lol +1 when I have my upvotes back. Perhaps you should explain why there is a `(c-1)*2` in the algorithm and why there is a `+ 1` for only the even rows. :)